# Как вызывать метод из generic метода без использования ограничений?

Tags: c#

Как в методе Generic класса вызвать метод не принадлежащий object без установления ограничения на тип? Проверка на существования метода уже произведена через рефлексию (т.е. метод точно есть у этого экземпляра). Экземпляр привести через as никуда нельзя т.к. он наследует только Object и не реализует ни один интерфейс.

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    void Foo(T a)
    {
        a.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите чего-то не того. А если кто-то запустит это не для вашего объекта? Как вариант - запускайте той же рефлексией, раз уж ею проверили наличие.

Comment: @ЯнГерманович, да, вполне себе вариант. Можете сами же ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Все равно спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Не совсем понятен смысл использования generic-метода

Answer (score 3):

Уже нашел решение через dynamic

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    void Foo(T a)
    {
        dynamic r = a;
        r.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Почему бы не закастить к нужному типу?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, правильнее было бы построить делегат для доступа в том же самом месте, где вы проверяете что метод существует. Точнее, сам процесс построения такого делегата был бы такой проверкой:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    static readonly Action<T> SomeMethodInvoker;
    static SomeClass()
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        // Строка ниже кинет исключение если метод не найден
        var body = Expression.Call(p, "SomeMethod", null); 
        SomeMethodInvoker = Expression.Labmda<Action<T>>(body, p).Compile();
    }

    void Foo(T a)
    {
        SomeMethodInvoker(a);
    }
}
```

Но если вам лень писать столько кода, можно воспользоваться `dynamic`. Внутрях у него все тот же самое построение выражения и его компиляция, только с доп. проверками:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
    void Foo(T a)
    {
        ((dynamic)a).SomeMethod();
    }
}
```